# Rerender screen after updating redux state in react-native

Tags: react-native

In my application, after updating a row of a flatlist from redux state,
it did not rendered as expected.

my code was

```
   // like Button Handler
    case SM_ACTION_LIKE:
      let updatedPosts = state.posts;

      updatedPosts.forEach(post => {
        if (post.shareId === action.payload.postId) {
          post.likeCount = action.payload.likeCount
        }
      });

      return {
        ...state,
        posts: updatedPosts
      };
      break;
```

After trying to find a solution to this issue, I used the following code, and it works as expected.

```
// like Button Handler
case SM_ACTION_LIKE:
  let updatedPosts = state.posts;

  updatedPosts.forEach(post => {
    if (post.shareId === action.payload.postId) {
      post.likeCount = action.payload.likeCount
    }
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    posts: updatedPosts.slice()
  };
  break;
```

Use of slice() at the end of the updatedPosts was the solution. Is this a good practice or what can be a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this works is `updatedPosts.slice()` returns a copy of posts which is what redux expects updates to state needs to be immutable.

The usual way to do this without using any immutable libraries would be using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator

```
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: [...updatedPosts]
  };
```

The other ways would be to use immutable libraries like [Immutablejs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) etc